# I have two wifi adapters (one internal and one USB), how do I identify the USB one via ifconfig?

Tags: linux

I bought a USB Wifi Adapter and shipped it along with a mini PC, and now I can't figure out which one is the USB wifi adapter based on `wlan0` and `wlan1`. I tried doing a mac address lookup to find the vendor, but no luck (neither of the two are documented). Here's an example of my ifconfig:

```
wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 86:4e:a5:a0:17:05  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 8e:60:7b:c5:40:09  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Here's an example of `lsusb`:

```
└─# lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0d8c:0014 C-Media Electronics, Inc. Audio Adapter (Unitek Y-247A)
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0e8d:7612 MediaTek Inc. MT7612U 802.11a/b/g/n/ac Wireless Adapter
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I'm trying to figure out which wlanX number the "MediaTek" adapter is. I tried using `iw list` to see if anything identifying there would help, but no luck. Any tips/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try lshw  .  That shows the NIC maker

Comment: I recommend using predictable net names. They were made for this very purpose.

Comment: unplug the adapter ... make a note of which MAC address disappears

Comment: Review the boot syslog (using the **dmesg** command). As each network interface is initialized, the driver usually reports the MAC address. Correlate that with the ether address from the **ifconfig** command.

Answer (score 0):

The device hierarchy is available through sysfs. Looking at the symlink targets under /sys/class/net will usually give some hints about which devices are on USB vs which ones are directly attached to PCI:

```
$ ls -l /sys/class/net/
lrwxrwxrwx [...] eno1 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:03:00.0/net/eno1/
lrwxrwxrwx [...] eno2 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:03:00.1/net/eno2/
lrwxrwxrwx [...] lo -> ../../devices/virtual/net/lo/
lrwxrwxrwx [...] rtl0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.0/net/rtl0/
```

Paths of PCI devices correspond to their hierarchy in `lspci -tvnn`, while paths of USB devices describe their position in `lsusb -tv` (e.g. "1-1.6" means bus 1 > port 1 > port 6).

For more details, use `udevadm info` to look at the properties collected by udev for each device (most of which are propagated from the parent PCI or USB devices):

```
$ udevadm info /sys/class/net/eno1
[...]
E: ID_OUI_FROM_DATABASE=Hewlett Packard Enterprise
E: ID_NET_NAME_ONBOARD=eno1
E: ID_NET_LABEL_ONBOARD=NIC Port 1
E: ID_BUS=pci
E: ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
E: ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=NetXtreme BCM5720 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (NC332i Adapter)
[...]

$ udevadm info /sys/class/net/rtl0
[...]
E: ID_OUI_FROM_DATABASE=TP-Link Corporation Limited
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_USB_VENDOR=Realtek
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=r8188eu
E: ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
E: ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter
[...]
```

Some network management tools automatically extract and show this information. For example, if you're using systemd-networkd, then `networkctl status wlan0` will show the model and path.

Also, if your distribution has it, `lsusb.py -i` will be easier to read than lsusb, *and* will directly show the network interfaces that a USB device provides. (Both lsusb and lsusb.py come from the same "usbutils", but many distributions don't package the latter for some reason.)

```
$ lsusb.py -i
usb1              1d6b:0002 09 1IF  [USB 2.00,  480 Mbps,   0mA] (ehci_hcd) hub
  1-1               8087:0024 09 1IF  [USB 2.00,  480 Mbps,   0mA] (Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub) hub
    1-1.6             0bda:8179 00 1IF  [USB 2.00,  480 Mbps, 500mA] (Realtek 802.11n NIC)
      1-1.6:1.0         (IF) ff:ff:ff 3EPs (Vendor Specific) r8188eu net/rtl0
```